# Why is my function returning undefined when its supposed to return an array?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I am creating a solution for piano teachers to document all of their student's pieces paperlessly. I am having an error: whenever I run my function, it returns undefined. Here's my code:

```js
class Student{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class StudentContainer{
    constructor(studentArr){
       this.students = studentArr;
    }
}

StudentContainer.prototype.studentExists = function(nameToSearch){
    
    for(var th in this.students){
        if(this.students[th].name == nameToSearch){
            return [true, parseInt(th)];
            break;
        }else if(parseInt(th)+1 == this.students.length){
            return [false, -1];
        
        }else{
       
        }
    }
   
}
StudentContainer.prototype.addStudent = function(studentToAdd){
    this.students[this.students.length] = studentToAdd;
}

StudentContainer.prototype.addStudentConditional = function(studentToAdd){
 var exists = this.studentExists(studentToAdd.name);
    console.log(exists); //undefined
    if(exists[0] == true){
         return {"success": false, "index": exists[1]};
    }else{
        this.students[this.students.length] = studentToAdd;
        return {"success": true, "index": this.students.length-1};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }
}
var y = new StudentContainer([]);
y.addStudentConditional(new Student("Sample"));
```

Error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
What's wrong? Any working snippets?

Comment: you don't return in all cases.

Comment: In particular you don't return in the case of an empty array, which is exactly what you're passing to the constructor.

Comment: OK!!! But wouldnt ```else if(parseInt(th)+1 == this.students.length){
            return [false, -1];
        
        }``` 
that return [false, -1] to an empty array?